# I want to create a straight line arrow using polyline in the Cesium Viewer. I'm using Firefox 40.0

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I'm trying to display a polyline using the Cesium Entities collection. I'm also using the entity.id to query the polyline and subsequently modify its position. The code below is basic. The Line is not displayed, (not rendered on the map).

......
obj = JSON.parse(myMsg);

```
var cmd      = obj.NET[0].CMD;
var eid      = obj.NET[0].ID;      // Entity ID
var lat1     = obj.NET[0].LAT1     // Latitude1
var lon1     = obj.NET[0].LON1;    // Longitude1
var alt1     = obj.NET[0].ALT1     // Altitude1
var lat2     = obj.NET[0].LAT2     // Latitude2
var lon2     = obj.NET[0].LON2     // Longitude2
var alt2     = obj.NET[0].ALT2     // Altitude2

var descr    = obj.NET[0].DESC;    // Description

var myArry = [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2];
var pos = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights(myArry);

if (cmd === "NEW") {
    viewer.entities.add({
        id : eid,
        polyline : {
            positions : pos,
            width : 5,
            followSurface : false,
            material : Cesium.Color.BLUE,
            show : true
        },
        description : descr,
    });
```

Any and all help would be appreciated (I'm new to the Cesium and also Javascript)

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the height values in `myArry`.

```
var myArry = [lon1, lat1, alt1, lon2, lat2, alt2];
var pos = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights(myArry);
```

Alternately, if you don't want heights, you could change

```
Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights(myArry)
```

to

```
Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(myArry)
```

For an example, see the [Polyline demo](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Polyline.html&label=Showcases).

Since you're new to JavaScript, I'll also add: Open the console (F12 in most browsers, Console tab) and look for errors there.  Try adding a `console.log('Added an entity.');` statement just before or after the `viewer.entities.add` block, so you can see if the code executed at all.

One more thing, the title of your question mentions you would like an arrow.  Try changing your `material` to:

```
material : new Cesium.PolylineArrowMaterialProperty(Cesium.Color.BLUE)
```